# Vertical layout padding

Tags: java, vaadin

1. Why components inside VerticalLayout are placed with some padding from edge?
2. How to solve this problem?

Code below demonstrates this issue:

```
@Component
@UIScope
public class TestForm extends CustomComponent {

    public TestForm() {

        HorizontalLayout hlayout = new HorizontalLayout();
        VerticalLayout vlayout = new VerticalLayout();
        hlayout.setSizeFull();
        vlayout.setStyleName("page");

        Label label1 = new Label("Label1");
        Label label2 = new Label("Label2");
        hlayout.addComponent(label1);
        vlayout.addComponent(label2);
        hlayout.addComponent(vlayout);

        setCompositionRoot(hlayout);
    }

}
```

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D653m.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Vaadin 8, the default for `VerticalLayout` is to have a "margin".  That means you get the padding you are experiencing per cell of the layout.  So put the `label2` in the place you want it to be, you have call to:

```
vlayout.setMargin(false)
```

Comment: I think spacing is also on by default, and you can remove that with `vlayout.setSpacing(false);`